# The meaning of the word "flack"

Tags: meaning, synonyms

Can I say "flack" means being criticized? 
Subway gets flack these days, but it's been the most consistent and dominating sub chain for 20 years for a reason.

Comment: Feliz Navidad. Can you include some context where the word would be used and your own reference/research on the word? It would be nicer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why yes, yes you can.  And you probably won't take any flak for it either. That's if you say it.  If you write it you may take some flak for the spelling.

> **flak**
>
> noun
>
> 1. antiaircraft fire, especially as experienced by the crews of combat airplanes at which the fire is directed.
> 2. criticism; hostile reaction; abuse:
>      Such an unpopular decision is bound to draw a lot of flak from the press.
>      Origin Expand
>      1935-40; < German Fl (ieger) a (bwehr) k (anone) antiaircraft gun, equivalent to Flieger aircraft (literally, flyer) + Abwehr defense + Kanone gun, cannon
>
> [dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/flack)

Meaning 2 is simply the metaphorical version of meaning 1. 2 may just be name calling while 1 might be sticks and stones (or other ammo).

> **flack**
>
> noun
>
> 1. a publicity agent.
>      "a public relations flack"
>
> verb
>
> 1. publicize or promote (something or someone).
>      "a crass ambulance-chaser who flacks himself in TV ads"
>
> [google.com](https://www.google.com/search?q=Flack&oq=Flack&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i59j69i60&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=0&ie=UTF-8)

> **flack vs. flak**
>
> A flack is a person—especially a press agent or publicist—who talks up his or her employer and deflects criticism. Flak (usually a mass noun) refers to (1) antiaircraft artillery, and (2) excessive or abusive criticism (the second definition derives metaphorically from the first).
>
> [grammarist.com](http://grammarist.com/spelling/flack-flak/)

Despite that you can find examples of either spelling for either meaning.  You can believe that's just people being sloppy spellers or that both spellings are for the same word (it was originally a german word) and the same metaphor.

Former White House press secretaries have a tradition of leaving notes to the new incoming press secretaries.  The notes contain advice about how to survive the job.  The notes, from every secretary since it started, are kept in a flak jacket.  A simple form of bullet proof vest worn by WWII pilots to protect them from flak.  It represents what it feels like to have to field questions from the press.

Comment: As German acronyms go *flak* is in the "easy" category.